# provisioning profile or entitlement error?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to put on my xamarin project the provisioning profile and the certificate...
But I am working with xamarin forms on my windows that is connectected to a physical mac...What happend is: when I need to run my project in a ios I run it through the windows and my mac does that...but for a physical device I need this cert. and prov. profile...
Will it work if I pass my project to my virtual mac and put there the certificate and provisioning profile and then pass it again to my windows? How my project will access the keychain in my windoews for my project? Do i need need to install the certificate in my windows ?? How do this things work? I'm a little confuse...I really need to do that
please, help me if you can
I did all this things and now my certificate works...but this error appears...I tried disabled keychain...but is still in this way...

My error

> Installation failed: Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile, check the iOS Device Log for details (error: 0xe8008016)

My provisioning profile appears normally on my developer account and in my project...its is linked to my certificate as well and my device is registered on apple developer account as well and its linked to my certificate too

I downloaded de provisioning in  my mac to...Is there a specific folder where it must to be ?

My IOS Device Log says:

> The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have everything set up correctly do develop on a windows PC and use a physical mac as a build device. I'm guessing you can run the app on a simulator and now need to connect and run it on an actual device.

I'm not sure what you mean by "virtual mac".

You need to follow the steps in [this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/) to create a certificate and provisioning profile.

Comment: the problem was: I had not installed the certificate on my mac...Now I did that...but now, it says that maybe my provisioning profile is not configured correctly or my entitlements doesn't support it...

Comment: forget the virtual mac...I think it doesn't make difference now

Answer (score 1):

I disabled all:
keychain
groups
pushnotifications
then, it worked...
the problem really was in entitlements

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "Entitlements.plist" from your configuration.

Project Option >  IOS Bundle Signing > Custom Entitlements (Keep it blank).

Comment: But then I can't use any of them.